# Get the SCM branch/tag name as playbook variable

Tags: ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I have a playbook which needs its own version at runtime to deploy various configuration.
Today I use a script which takes a `version` parameter then git clone/checkout to this version and finally call ansible-playbook with `-e project_version=$version`.

This is fine and all but now I would like to use AWX instead.

There is the "SCM Branch" parameter when launching a job, but it doesn't seem to be exposed during the playbook run.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Here are the (ugly) workarounds I could think of:

- Manually add the `project_version` extra variable when launching the AWX job (so the version has to be entered twice each time)
- Change the playbook to retrieve the git tag/branch/commit label at runtime (which is not so simple because AWX does not do a proper git clone)
- Bypass AWX by making it checkout an intermediary project (closer to my existing script)

Comment: I created a feature request in case this is really not possible: https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/8429

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the commit number you can use the variable `awx_project_revision` in AWX and `tower_project_revision` in Ansible Tower. Those variables are added to the job environment automatically when you run your template.

Comment: Thanks, but as you say it only stores the commit hash.Here I want the human readable tag/branch name I put in "SCM Branch" in the AWX UI.